# ProcessBuilder not displaying output stream if it is java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I got a code which is running and displaying output successfully if I am executing something like "dir" but not displaying the output if I am running "java -version" or other command from java. Please help:

```
public static void execJob(){

    try{        

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\myPrograms\\jdk1.7.0_79\\bin\\java.exe", "-version");
    pb.directory(new File("src"));
    Process process = pb.start();
    IOThreadHandler outputHandler = new IOThreadHandler(process.getInputStream());
    outputHandler.start();
    process.waitFor();

    System.out.println(outputHandler.getOutput());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}

private static class IOThreadHandler extends Thread {
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    IOThreadHandler(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public void run() {
        Scanner br = null;
        try {
            br = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;
            while (br.hasNextLine()) {
                line = br.nextLine();
                output.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: First do e.printStacktrace instead of e.toString

Comment: Try [`ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29), check that it's writing to stdout and not stderr.

Comment: Thanks Elliott but inheritIO() didn't help. Any other suggestions..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java -version` writes to stderr, so you need `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` to capture the output.

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\myPrograms\\jdk1.7.0_79\\bin\\java.exe", "-version");
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 ...
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it is writing now. Actually I am trying to do run java programs from command line and display the output live and it is not displaying the output which is very important. why calling some jar and displaying output not working even if java version is working now. Any idea

Answer (score -1):

```
private static class IOThreadHandler extends Thread {
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    IOThreadHandler(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public void run() {
        try (Scanner br = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
            String line = null;
            while (br.hasNextLine()) {
                line = br.nextLine();
                output.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        }
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```